# Show that a subset $V$ of $X$ is open iff every point $x \in V$ has a neighborhood $V_x \subseteq V$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Show that a subset $V$ of $X$ is open iff every point $x \in V$ has a neighborhood $V_x \subseteq V$.

Any help would be appreciated. I am working in topological spaces right now.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you having more trouble with one half of the implication than the other?

Comment: @MikeF I don't particularly know how to start. I know that if $(X,\gamma)$ is a topological space, then the sets in$\gamma$ are open sets. Moreover, for each point $x \in X$, an open set containing $x$ is a neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: @MikeF If we have $U$ as a subset of $X$ and its open, doesn't that get us that $U$ is a neighborhood around $x$?

Answer (score 3):

$\Rightarrow$:

For each $x$, take $V_x=V$

$\Leftarrow$

For each $x$, choose a $V_x$. We have that $\displaystyle V=\bigcup_{x \in V} V_x$. But then $V$ is open.

I tried to be concise so you can fill the details that you feel uncomfortable with. : )

Comment: I understand we let $V$ (the open subset of $X$) be the $V_x$ which is our neighborhood for all $x \in X$. But I do not understand why this gives us our forward direction automatically. What is our definition of open other than it being a set in $\gamma$?

Answer (score 3):

Considering the fact that implication $\Rightarrow$ is clear, you can finish the other implication and therefore your "proof" by realizing that
\begin{equation}
V = \bigcup_{x \in V} \{x\} \subset \bigcup_{V_x \subset V} V_{x} \subset V
\, .\end{equation}
That gives us that V is an union of open sets.